# Bash: doubly looping don't work

Tags: linux

I have this loop but it doesn't work :-/

```
for i in *CCDSxBaseCov.bed
    do SM=`(echo $i | sed 's/.bed//g')`; echo $SM
        for chr in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 X Y M; do echo "-- chr$chr --"; bases=`(grep chr$chr "${SM}_hg19_EXONSxBaseCov.bed" | wc -l)`; echo "EXONS target length=$bases"; cov=`(grep chr$chr "${SM}_hg19_EXONSxBaseCov.bed" | awk '{sum+=$3} END {print sum}')`; echo "sum EXONS bases coverage=$cov"; avercov=$(($cov/$bases)); echo "EXONS average coverage=$avercov" >> ${SM}_hg19_EXONScovstats.txt
        done
    done
```

The second loop alone works

Comment: And the outer one? Does it print the $SM? For investing the problem, using some linebreaks wouldn't be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Comment the inner for, if it works on it's own and mask the $i, since it is a filename, which might contain spaces. Use $(...) instead of the deprecated backticks.

```
for i in *CCDSxBaseCov.bed
    do SM=$((echo "$i" | sed 's/.bed//g')); echo $SM
        # for chr in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 X Y M; do echo "-- chr$chr --"; bases=`(grep chr$chr "${SM}_hg19_EXONSxBaseCov.bed" | wc -l)`; echo "EXONS target length=$bases"; cov=`(grep chr$chr "${SM}_hg19_EXONSxBaseCov.bed" | awk '{sum+=$3} END {print sum}')`; echo "sum EXONS bases coverage=$cov"; avercov=$(($cov/$bases)); echo "EXONS average coverage=$avercov" >> ${SM}_hg19_EXONScovstats.txt
        # done
    done
```